# Kivy change keyboard layout for different text inputs

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am having a hard time changing between keyboard layouts in my app. In the below example I have two text fields and I want one to use a regular keyboard and the other to use a numberpad keyboard. When I click within one text field the keyboard changes, but focus is lost.

Is there a better way of changing a keyboard based on what field currently has focus?

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'dock')

from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

Window.size = (480, 600)
Window.borderless = False

KV = '''
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "center"
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.5

        MDTextField:
            id: textField
            hint_text: "Text field"
            mode: "rectangle"
            on_focus: app.changeKeyboard(textField, 'keyboard_text.json')

        MDTextField:
            id: numberField
            hint_text: "Number field"
            mode: "rectangle"
            on_focus: app.changeKeyboard(textField, 'keyboard_number.json')
'''


class MyApp(MDApp):
    textField = ObjectProperty()
    numberField = ObjectProperty()

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def changeKeyboard(self, widget, layout):
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, widget)

        if self._keyboard.widget:
            vkeyboard = self._keyboard.widget
            vkeyboard.layout = layout

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard has been closed!')
        self._keyboard = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I made it work for me with specialized TextInput classes:

### main.py

```
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('kivy', 'keyboard_mode', 'dock')

from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

import interface.paths as paths
import os

Window.size = (480, 600)
Window.borderless = False

KV = '''
    
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "center"
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: 0.9, 0.5

        NumericInput:
            id: numberField
            hint_text: "50"
                
        AlphaNumericInput:
            id: textField
            hint_text: "Number field"
                
'''

class NumericInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NumericInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_focus(self, instance, value):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.changeKeyboard(self, 'numeric')


class AlphaNumericInput(TextInput):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(AlphaNumericInput, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_focus(self, instance, value):
        app = App.get_running_app()
        app.changeKeyboard(self, 'alphanumeric')
        

class MyApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def changeKeyboard(self, widget, layout):
        print(f'Changing keyboard layout to: {layout}')
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, widget)

        layout_mapping = {'numeric': os.path.join('config', 'keyboards', 'numeric.json'), 
                        'alphanumeric': os.path.join('config', 'keyboards', 'en_US.json')}

        if self._keyboard.widget:
            vkeyboard = self._keyboard.widget
            vkeyboard.layout = layout_mapping[layout]
        

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        print('My keyboard has been closed!')
        if self._keyboard:
            self._keyboard = None
            Window.release_keyboard()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

### en_US.json

```
{
    "title": "en_US",
    "description": "A US Keyboard, touch optimized (no shift+caps lock)",
    "cols": 10,
    "rows": 5,
    
    "normal_1" : [
        ["1", "1", "1", 1],
        ["2", "2", "2", 1],
        ["3", "3", "3", 1],
        ["4", "4", "4", 1],
        ["5", "5", "5", 1],
        ["6", "6", "6", 1],
        ["7", "7", "7", 1],
        ["8", "8", "8", 1],
        ["9", "9", "9", 1],
        ["0", "0", "0", 1]
    ],
    "normal_2" : [
        ["q", "q", "q", 1],
        ["w", "w", "w", 1],
        ["e", "e", "e", 1],
        ["r", "r", "r", 1],
        ["t", "t", "t", 1],
        ["y", "y", "y", 1],
        ["u", "u", "u", 1],
        ["i", "i", "i", 1],
        ["o", "o", "o", 1],
        ["p", "p", "p", 1]
    ],
    "normal_3" : [
        ["a", "a", "a", 1.11],
        ["s", "s", "s", 1.11],
        ["d", "d", "d", 1.11],
        ["f", "f", "f", 1.11],
        ["g", "g", "g", 1.11],
        ["h", "h", "h", 1.11],
        ["j", "j", "j", 1.11],
        ["k", "k", "k", 1.11],
        ["l", "l", "l", 1.11]
    ],
    "normal_4" : [
        ["\u21e7", null, "capslock", 1.5],
        ["z", "z", "z", 1],
        ["x", "x", "x", 1],
        ["c", "c", "c", 1],
        ["v", "v", "v", 1],
        ["b", "b", "b", 1],
        ["n", "n", "n", 1],
        ["m", "m", "m", 1],
        ["\u232b", null, "backspace", 1.5]
    ],
    "normal_5" : [
        ["#+=", null, "special", 2],
        [" ", " ", " ", 6],
        ["done", "done", "done", 2]
    ],



    "shift_1" : [
        ["1", "1", "1", 1],
        ["2", "2", "2", 1],
        ["3", "3", "3", 1],
        ["4", "4", "4", 1],
        ["5", "5", "5", 1],
        ["6", "6", "6", 1],
        ["7", "7", "7", 1],
        ["8", "8", "8", 1],
        ["9", "9", "9", 1],
        ["0", "0", "0", 1]
    ],
    "shift_2" : [
        ["Q", "Q", "Q", 1],
        ["W", "W", "W", 1],
        ["E", "E", "E", 1],
        ["R", "R", "R", 1],
        ["T", "T", "T", 1],
        ["Y", "Y", "Y", 1],
        ["U", "U", "U", 1],
        ["I", "I", "I", 1],
        ["O", "O", "O", 1],
        ["P", "P", "P", 1]
    ],
    "shift_3" : [
        ["A", "A", "A", 1],
        ["S", "S", "S", 1],
        ["D", "D", "D", 1],
        ["F", "F", "F", 1],
        ["G", "G", "G", 1],
        ["H", "H", "H", 1],
        ["J", "J", "J", 1],
        ["K", "K", "K", 1],
        ["L", "L", "L", 1]
    ],
    "shift_4" : [
        ["\u21e7", null, "capslock", 2],
        ["Z", "Z", "Z", 1],
        ["X", "X", "X", 1],
        ["C", "C", "C", 1],
        ["V", "V", "V", 1],
        ["B", "B", "B", 1],
        ["N", "N", "N", 1],
        ["M", "M", "M", 1],
        ["\u232b", null, "backspace", 2]
    ],
    "shift_5" : [
        ["#+=", null, "special", 2],
        [" ", " ", " ", 8],
        ["done", "done", "done", 2]
    ],

    "special_1": [
        ["@", "@", "@", 1],
        ["?", "?", "?", 1],
        ["!", "!", "!", 1],
        [";", ";", ";", 1],
        ["•", "•", "•", 1],
        ["|", "|", "|", 1],
        ["\\", "\\", "\\", 1],
        ["˘", "˘", "˘", 1],
        ["-", "-", "-", 1],
        ["|", "|", "|", 1]
    ],
    "special_2": [
        ["(", "(", "(", 1],
        [")", ")", ")", 1],
        ["{", "{", "{", 1],
        ["}", "}", "}", 1],
        ["[", "[", "[", 1],
        ["]", "]", "]", 1],
        ["€", "€", "€", 1],
        ["$", "$", "$", 1],
        ["£", "£", "£", 1],
        ["¥", "¥", "¥", 1]
    ],
    "special_3": [
        ["“", "“", "“", 1],
        ["`", "`", "`", 1],
        ["«", "«", "«", 1],
        ["»", "»", "»", 1],
        ["#", "#", "#", 1],
        ["%", "%", "%", 1],
        ["^", "^", "^", 1],
        ["°", "°", "°", 1],
        ["&", "&", "&", 1]
    ],
    "special_4": [
        ["+", "+", "+", 1],
        ["=", "=", "=", 1],
        ["<", "<", "<", 1],
        [">", ">", ">", 1],
        ["*", "*", "*", 1],
        ["~", "~", "~", 1],
        [":", ":", ":", 1],
        ["_", "_", "_", 1],
        ["-", "-", "-", 1]
    ],
    "special_5": [
        ["#+=", null, "special", 2],
        [" ", " ", " ", 11],
        ["done", "done", "done", 2]
    ]
    
}
```

### numeric.json

```
{
"title" : "Numeric",
"description" : "A numeric keypad",
"cols" : 3,
"rows": 4,
"normal_1": [
["7", "7", "7", 1],
["8", "8", "8", 1],
["9", "9", "9", 1]],
"normal_2": [
["4", "4", "4", 1],
["5", "5", "5", 1],
["6", "6", "6", 1]],
"normal_3": [
["1", "1", "1", 1],
["2", "2", "2", 1],
["3", "3", "3", 1]],
"normal_4": [
["0", "0", "0", 1],
[".", ".", ".", 1],
["\u232b", null, "backspace", 1]],
"shift_1": [
["7", "7", "7", 1],
["8", "8", "8", 1],
["9", "9", "9", 1]],
"shift_2": [
["4", "4", "4", 1],
["5", "5", "5", 1],
["6", "6", "6", 1]],
"shift_3": [
["1", "1", "1", 1],
["2", "2", "2", 1],
["3", "3", "3", 1]],
"shift_4": [
["0", "0", "0", 1],
[".", ".", ".", 1],
["\u232b", null, "backspace", 1]]
}
```

---